# TSQL - Query XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Maybe some can help me, i have got an sql table with nRows with an XML-Column.
The XML structure looks like this:

```
<DynamicResults>
  <RegQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.o....." xmlns:xsd="http://....." REGServer="localhost" REGHive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" REGSubKey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\BlaBla" />
</DynamicResults>
```

my question: how can i query into the xml, i'd like to know if an /DynamicResults/RegQuery with an specified value in the attribute 'REGSubKey' has subnodes...

thanks a lot

Comment: @podiluska - thank you for your solution - but i got one further problem at this. how could i use a declared value to paste - because:
'....[@RegSubKey=' + myDeclaredVarcharWithQuotationMarks + ']/*','int'...... dont work

Comment: You need to use `sql:variable(yourvariablename)`

Comment: @podiluska 
sql:variable("@yourvariablename") worked for me - thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from table
where XmlField.value('count(/DynamicResults/RegQuery[@REGSubKey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\BlaBla"]/*)','int')>0
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I normally do this is to use the built-in XML functions (if you're using SQL Server 2005 or later).

Check out this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030

Here is an example which returns the number of sub nodes for the specific reg key `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\BlaBla`...

```
DECLARE @x xml 
SET @x='<DynamicResults>
  <RegQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.o....." xmlns:xsd="http://....." REGServer="localhost" REGHive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" REGSubKey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\BlaBla">
    <SubNode />
    <SubNode />
  </RegQuery>
  <RegQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.o....." xmlns:xsd="http://....." REGServer="localhost" REGHive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" REGSubKey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\BlaBla2" />
  <RegQuery xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.o....." xmlns:xsd="http://....." REGServer="localhost" REGHive="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" REGSubKey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\BlaBla3" />
</DynamicResults>'
SELECT @x.value('count(/DynamicResults/RegQuery[@REGSubKey="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\BlaBla"]/*)','INT')
GO
```